# Proper way of initializing NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have an ivar which is a `NSMutableArray`. I've seen some people use this function as a way to initialize an array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)varArray
{
   if (!varArray)
      varArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   return varArray;
}
```

And the array is released in `dealloc`.

When I tried to do this, sometimes the array is initialized, sometimes not.

So what I'm asking is, Is this a good way to initialize an ivar `NSMutableArray`, or is it better to do this: `varArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];` instead?

Comment: How do you access your array when you say "sometimes the array is initialized, sometimes not"?

Comment: Additionally... do you know if you are deallocing the object at all between queries of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this line:

`varArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Is always fine, but in which function is where it matters. It appears you are initializing it in the variable's setter, so whenever you query for that instance variable it should always exist... in theory. But issues may occur if you merely dealloc the ivar without setting it to nil so the following will explicitly reset the ivar pointer so that it is guaranteed to be nil  when dealloced:

```
[varArray dealloc];
varArray = nil;
```

This will ensure your `if (!varArray)` check will be correct.

Comment: Oh! So that must be the reason why sometimes the array is not initialized. I will try it first before I accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> So what I'm asking is, Is this a good way to initialize an ivar NSMutableArray

**No.**

Simply implement your object's designated initializer and initialize the array there:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 == self)
    return 0;
  varArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you explain why is it not a good way to initialize an array?

Comment: @AnnaFortuna sure. because there's no reason to do this lazily. if it were an expensive operation (e.g. running out to disk or network), that would be another consideration. however, it's just an empty array. lazy initialization only introduces unnecessary complexity, which makes it more difficult to maintain and is a leaky abstraction. create it in init, destroy it in dealloc. done. invariance is powerful/simple -- eliminate a class of threading issues, eliminate potential memory management issues. either eliminate or simplify the setter. eliminate runtime checks. and so on…